# Windows fourm crashes after clicking button

Tags: c#

I decided to create a basic timer just for my use and everytime i click the start button the program freezes up completely. Im i missing something obvious or?

```
namespace Timer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int secs = 0, mins = 0, hours = 0;

            for (int num1 = 1; num1 > 0;)
            {
                txt_secs.Text = secs.ToString() ;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                secs = secs + 1;

                if (secs == 60)
                {
                    secs = 0;
                    mins = mins + 1;
                    txt_mins.Text = mins.ToString();
                }
                if (mins == 60)
                {
                    mins = 0;
                    hours = hours + 1;
                    txt_hours.Text = hours.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't incrementing num1 in your for loop maybe?

Comment: Never do a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` on the UI thread of a form application

Comment: you've got an endless loop. define a terminating condition for the for loop (like `num1 <= 100`) or break out of the loop when you're done. for periodic jobs, use a `System.Timer` that would run on a different thread and not block the user interface.

Comment: If you want to see something to happen in that loop you need to add an Application.DoEvents at the end of the loop

Comment: the loop does not yield to the user interface thread, that's what makes it freeze.

Comment: @Steve or just correctly use a Timer to do the loop

Comment: How do i use the timers?

Comment: Sure.... but just to make it clear where the first error is

Comment: Random note, it might be easier to read if you use `while(true)` for an infinite loop rather than using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `System.Threading.Sleep()`

Per [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx) your thread will be suspended. The thread is in an infinite loop and thus will be (essentially) permanently suspended.

Consider using [Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [Stopwatch Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) or (if you need threading) [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) Instead